# WSL does not open in current directory working directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Typing bash into explorer address bar or opening WSL through windows terminal does not open it in the current directory. WSL always open at the root directory `/`.

I have checked this command in powershell `(Get-ItemProperty -name "(default)" -LiteralPath Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\WSL\command).'(default)'` as instructed on another question, the output is as expected: `wsl.exe --cd "%V"`

I even tried running the command `wsl.exe --cd "C:/random/path/to/some/directory"` and regardless of the path WSL always opens in `/`.

Interestingly, if I open wsl by typing `ubuntu` into cmd or powershell it will open bash in my `/home/username/` directory.

Has anyone had this issue? How can I fix it?

**EDIT** adding the folling lines to my wsl.conf seems to have fixed the issue but I have no idea why, can anyone explain?

```
# Enable extra metadata options by default
[automount]
enabled = true
root = /windir/
options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
mountFsTab = false
```

**EDIT2** I went through a process of elimination, removing one line at a time trying to figure out which of these lines did the trick. shutting down and restarting wsl everytime I deleted a line WSL kept opening in the correct directory, and i eventually deleted all the lines and it still wokring. WSL continues to open in the correct directory even after i deleted the wsl.conf file. I'm so confused
**EDIT3**

```
cat ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
cat: /home/rwagh/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `whoami` `cat ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: what should i do with the output? you can see the output in EDIT3